# C# and ASP.NET MVC runtime timeout of user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, timeout

I'm having a problem with timeout of user.

I created an ASP.NET MVC web application, added references for Web API, and authentication, individual user accounts, in VS 2017. I have worked on the app for a while, the Web API works fine. I got the app up running on IIS. Users get created and login. Nice.

**BUT**: the app has not ever, as far as I know, logged out any user after a period of inactivity. This is a problem since the app is for serious use and data must be fairly protected.

In `web.config` I have :

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="2" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name="userLogin" timeout="2" loginUrl="~/Account  /Login" slidingExpiration="true" />
    </authentication>
    <!--https://forums.asp.net/t/1573943.aspx?SessionState+Timeout+vs+httpruntime+executionTimeout-->
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <!--<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />-->
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="2147483647" 
                 executionTimeout="600" requestLengthDiskThreshold="2147483647" />
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" 
             type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

I am lost here. What is needed to do if user be logged out after 5 minutes of inactivity?

Answer (score 0):

Is your issue here that the user isn't being logged out, or that the web page the user is on never changes even though two minutes have passed?

If it's the latter, then the expiration of the authentication session or the cookies will not effect the page the user is on.

If not, you can ignore this answer.

Your best bet if you want the user to get kicked out to the login screen after five minutes is to set up a javascript timer on your master/home/shared view that, after the time you specify elapses, redirects the user to the home screen.  MVC will not do that for you, or I'm not aware of any setting that will cause it to.

Comment: The issue is that the user isn't being logged out. The user can continue working after hours away which is not good security The user should be returned to the login view after inactivity. thx